# Jquery associate two arrays (key, value) into one array with duplicate key

Tags: javascript

thanks in advance if the array is

```
var animals = ['Cow', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
```

how can i get a assoc array like this

```
 // returns {'Cow': 'Moo', 'Cow': 'Oink', 'Dog': 'Woof', 'Cat': 'Miao'}
```

Comment: You mean "Pig" for the second "Cow", right? You can't have an object with two identical keys.

Comment: How? Write an algorithm and code it. Nobody here will code it for you. That's not the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 1):

JS Fiddle of all 3 options: http://jsfiddle.net/ysLvfxmd/2/

You want a hash/associative array, loop through and create one by index, however you cannot have duplicate keys in a hash so you may want to explore other data structures.

**Pure Hash**

```
var animals = ['Cow', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
var hash = {};

for(i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    hash[animals[i]] = sounds[i];
}

console.log(hash);
```

This will only show Cow once, if you want to have pairs of this with non-unique keys you need to make an array of hashes

**Array Of Hashes**

```
var animals = ['Cow', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
var arr = [];

for(i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    var hash = {};
    hash[animals[i]] = sounds[i];
    arr.push(hash);
}

console.log(arr);
```

However, note that the indexes of the array are now numeric but you can search through it to find your values.

Third Option:

**Hash Of Arrays (Best)**

```
//Paul Rob's suggestion hash of arrays

var animals = ['Cow', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
var hashOfArr = [];

for(i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    if(!hashOfArr[animals[i]]){
        hashOfArr[animals[i]] = [];
    }
    hashOfArr[animals[i]].push(sounds[i]);
}
console.log(hashOfArr);
```

Comment: Seems more sensible to go with a hash of arrays, e.g. `{ 'Cow':['Moo', 'Oink'], 'Dog': ['Woof'], 'Cat': ['Miao'] }`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing after I wrote it, let me add another example for that

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

What you exactly want is impossible. Objects cannot have multiple keys.

## My suggestion

Have an object where the value of each key is an array. If an animal have multiple sound, you'll only have to push it into the array.

```
var
animals = ['Cow', 'Cow', 'Dog', 'Cat'],
sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'],
result = {};

for(i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    result[animals[i]]
        ? result[animals[i]].push(sounds[i])
        : result[animals[i]] = [sounds[i]];
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py99LttL/)